# How can I change a UIBarButtonItem's TintColor when building for iOS 6.1 and running under iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, ios7, uibarbuttonitem, tintcolor

I have an iOS app compiled using the 6.1 SDK with some UIBarButtonItems where the TintColor is set programmatically in ViewWillAppear.

```
UIBarButtonItem leftButton = new UIBarButtonItem(...);
leftButton.TintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(231, 231, 231);
```

Resulting in this.

[image: Custom UIBarButtonItem TintColor on 6.1]

I've upgraded my iPhone to 7.0 but I still need to build for the 6.1 SDK for backwards device compatibility (business reasons).

When I build the app using the 6.1 SDK and run it on an iPhone running iOS 7.0, the toolbar looks like this.

[image: Custom UIBarButtonItem TintColor on 7.0]

Having read through the iOS 7 UI Transition Guide, I tried setting the UIWindow's TintColor to see if this had an effect. It did not.

On interesting thing - on this form, when I display an ActionSheet, after the ActionSheet is dismissed, the background of the Cancel and Save buttons changes from "black" to "white". I'm currently investigating why this happens.

If I can't change the TintColor programmatically under iOS 7.0 I'm thinking of creating custom background images for the buttons, like this.

[image: Greyish Button]

And use SetBackgroundImage to override the existing background.

Thanks in advance.

**Update - 09.24.13**

poupou's answer pointed me to the WWDC video ([link](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/index.php?id=214)) which gave me the solution at 8:37 - I need to set the navigation bar's TintColor instead of setting the specific button's TintColor.

```
NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(231, 231, 231);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried setting the UIWindow's TintColor to see if this had an effect. It did not.

It should - but if you're setting `TintColor` on some other UI elements then it will have priority over the one set on the main `UIWindow`.

There's a whole session of WWDC 2013 (session 214) about `TintColor` and how it works in iOS7 (that's the one with the Tic Tac Toe sample).

If you need to run/exclude some code specific to an iOS version you can do:

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (7,0)) {
    // iOS 7.0 and later
} else {
    // iOS 6.1 and earlier
}
```